# "except" não reconhece valor como errado

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
mensagem = input('''Clique "C" ''')
print (mensagem)

#condições relativas ao input mensagem

try : 
    mensagem == "C"
except Exception :
    print ("a casa caiu")
else :
    print ("a casa não caiu")
```

> O programa sempre está rodando "a casa não caiu", queria saber o porquê e como consertar

Comment: Esse código realmente não vai gerar exceção, você queria que uma exceção fosse gerada caso o valor fosse diferente de "C"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não quer usar uma exceção aí, só quer verificar um estado e tomar uma decisão, e para tomar decisões e desviar o fluxo existe o comando `if`.

Como o próprio nome diz, uma exceção só deve ser usada em casos excepcionais. Quase sempre quando alguém usa uma exceção está fazendo algo errado no código. Python até incentiva um pouco o uso de exceção em coisas não muito excepcionais, mas aí pelo menos é questão de interpretação do que é excepcional ou não, o seu caso claramente não é algo excepcional, é só uma decisão. A não ser que tenha algo não colocado na pergunta.

Nem faz sentido ter uma condição sozinha assim, ou teria que guardar o valor em uma variável para uso futuro ou usar exatamente em uma condição (um `if`, `while` ou algo assim).

Com `if` faz o que deseja:

```
mensagem = input('''Clique "C" ''')
print (mensagem)
if mensagem == "C":
    print("a casa caiu")
else:
    print("a casa não caiu")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZvE6NR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Conditionpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Condition.py).