# Except não está capturando a exceção

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
mensagem_de_modalidade = int (input ('''
Como você quer jogar ?
1)Solo
2)Em dupla
3)Em trio'''))


try :
        if mensagem_de_modalidade == 1 :
                print ("oi")
        if mensagem_de_modalidade == 2 :
                print ("hi")
        if mensagem_de_modalidade == 3 :
                print ("sla")


except :
        print ("TESTE")
```

Comment: O Maniero lhe respondeu isso em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440344/3635, não tem sentido usar try pra algo que não é emite exceção, não tem pq perguntar novamente se não entendeu algo, comentei lá aonde já fez a primeira pergunta.

Comment: É que quando entra na exceção do "except" o programa mostra oq tem dentro do bloco e fecha. Agora se eu tivesse usado o "else" o programa continuaria rodando normalmente, oq eu não queria

Comment: @Smaug você pode por favor remover a aceitação da minha resposta ? Quando você leu a resposta e a aceitou, ela não estava correta.

Answer (score 3):

Acontece que o que você está tentando capturar não é tido como exceção, pois é algo que somente não está dentro de nenhum `if`. O código que poderia capturar essa opção não válida deveria ser mais ou menos assim:

```
mensagem_de_modalidade = int (input ('''
Como você quer jogar ?
1)Solo
2)Em dupla
3)Em trio'''))

if mensagem_de_modalidade == 1 :
    print ("oi")
elif mensagem_de_modalidade == 2 :    
    print ("hi")
elif mensagem_de_modalidade == 3 :
    print('sla')
else:
    print("TESTE")
```

Comment: É que eu queria que o programa fechasse se entrasse na exceção, aí eu achei melhor usar o "except" ao invés do "else", mas, se tiver alguma maneira disso acontecer usando o "else", você pode dizer como se faz, assim, pro código ficar melhor

Comment: @Smaug ele disse, eu já disse para você em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/440341/except-n%c3%a3o-reconhece-valor-como-errado.